# Indexing numbers with a function?

Tags: python

I am trying to have my code find every other number from a given number within my function. For instance, my code looks like:

```
def credit_card(number):
  check = float(number[1::2])
  return check

print(credit_card(123456789))
```

I want it to return `2,4,6,8`.

Comment: You're trying to use string indexing on an integer, and then converting that to a `float`.  You've entirely confused the Python parser.  Break this down into individual operations; when you have the correct output from that, *then* combine them into one line.

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert it to string first. Integer is not iterable in Python

```
def credit_card(number):
  check = str(number)[1::2]
  return [int(i) for i in check]
```